# VSTS to TFS 2015 Test Case Import

Tags: testing, tfs, azure-devops

Hi there we have a requirement to duplicate our test cases (hosted in VSTS) witht he clients on-prem version of TFS 2015.

Both instances use and are licenced with MTM. Is there a way export our VSTS Test Cases and Import them for duplicated functional testing in the clients on-prem TFS2015?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to export/import the Test Cases with the basic information, then you can export test cases from VSTS to MS excel, then edit and import to on-premise TFS, reference this thread: [How to Export and Import Test Cases from Visual Studio Team Services into MS Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44501382/how-to-export-and-import-test-cases-from-visual-studio-team-services-into-ms-exc)

But it's difficult to migrate/duplicate Test Cases separately between VSTS and TFS **with parameters and attachments**.  See [Bulk Migrate Work Item Comments, Links and Attachments](http://colinsalmcorner.com/post/bulk-migrate-work-item-comments-links-and-attachments)

> **Test Cases**
>
> Test plans/suites/cases turned out to be particularly
>   difficult to migrate. We couldn’t find any tooling that would be able
>   to do this for us. It’s possible to manage tests using the TFS SDK
>   on-premise, and there is a restful API for VSTS, so a custom solution
>   could be produced where time is permitting.
>
> Unfortunately, Excel was out of the question, as test plans and suites
>   cannot be queried as usual and test cases when published were not
>   possible to be linked to a test suite or plan.
>   ***[Source Here](https://technology.cap-hpi.com/blog/migrating-from-on-premise-tfs-to-visual-studio-team-services/)***

You can also reference below similar threads:

- [Migrate Test Cases from TFS to VSTS along with parameters and attachments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47432970/migrate-test-cases-from-tfs-to-vsts-along-with-parameters-and-attachments)
- [How to migrate MTM Test Cases from TFS 2013 to VSTS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39836734/how-to-migrate-mtm-test-cases-from-tfs-2013-to-vsts)

Comment: @Nick Paterakis Have you resolved the issue? any update?